# Ubuntu 14.04 - Installed Ubuntu SDK and getting errors on start up

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I figured I wanted to check out some Ubuntu app development, and followed the "guide" on https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/, but it's not quite as simple as the guide would have you know.

First I'm getting a lot permission errors from the /home/.config/Qt* directory. I figure I should change ownership and permissions to those libraries from root to my user?

Besides that I'm getting these errors in the Qt Creator general messages after startup:

```
E: 10mount: mount: unknown filesystem type 'overlayfs'
E: 15binfmt: update-binfmts: unable to open /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-8205ef1a-f62f-4571-b470-987ff4002e54/bin/sh: No such file or directory
E: click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf-8205ef1a-f62f-4571-b470-987ff4002e54: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
Command returned 1: schroot -c click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf -- env DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_ARCH=armhf DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_BUILD_ARCH=amd64 DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=arm DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=arm DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=x86_64 DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=64 DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=amd64 cmake -DQT_IMPORTS_DIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml --help
```

If I try to run the simple app template it just builds an nothing happens...

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working?

UPDATE:

When trying to install my kits I get these errors:

```
unable to initialize frontend: Readlinedebconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletypedebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialogdebconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the minimum requirement for the SDK is 14.10.

Secondly, yes you can safely changes the permissions on the /home/user/.config folder, just make sure that the ubuntudevice_id_rsa in the .config/ubuntu-sdk folder has 400 permission.

Comment: That's not what it says on their website - [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/) it states that the Ubuntu SDK is available from 14.04 and onwards